# Create a class constructor that initializes object variables of other types based on parmeters (C#)

Tags: c#, class, parameters, constructor

I'm new to coding so I hope this is clear...

I have created two new classes: a student, and a gradebook. Their constructors are as follows:

```
Student(string studentName, string gradeBookTitle);

Gradebook(double testWeight, double quizWeight, 
          double assignmentWeight, string[] studentNameArray);
```

I want to use the names in the Gradebook.studentNameArray parameter to initialize a Student object for each name. This way, when a user creates a gradebook, they would automatically create a Student object for each student in the class.

However, I'm running into problems because you cannot use the contents of an array to name a new variable. I'm assuming that I'm overthinking it... is there an easier way to organize all of this? Or another way to create those student variables inside the constructor?

Comment: `I'm running into problems because you cannot use the contents of an array to name a new variable` What?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot OP is asking the same question that a lot of new programmers ask: how to dynamically name a variable.. which is almost always the wrong question to be asking.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, care to explain why it's the wrong question? Is there just usually a sleeker way?

Comment: There isn't a way to do it.. that's why its the wrong question. If you're heading into the "it's not possible to do it" territory, you're generally thinking about what you're trying to do incorrectly.

Comment: Why are you initializing a student object with age being a required parameter if you don't have that information when you create the gradebook? It looks like you only have a list of student names - without ages.

Comment: @Geek, thanks for noticing my mistake. I was editing my code slightly to make it clearer for the example, and forgot to remove that part. Successfully edited!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary`, with the `Key` being the student's name. Somewhat like this (making some assumptions here, but hopefully this shows you the basic idea):

```
public IDictionary<string, Student> StudentDictionary { get; set; }

public Gradebook(double testWeight, double quizWeight, 
                 double assignmentWeight, string[] studentNameArray) {

    StudentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Student>();

    foreach (var name in studentNameArray) {
        StudentDictionary.Add(name, new Student(name, <age_here>, this.Title));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if two students have the same name?  What benefit does he get by using a dictionary?  A List<Student> seems more appropriate here.

Comment: "Making some assumptions here". One of them being that a student's name is sufficiently unique.

Answer (score 1):

User.. Does student have another constructor or which default values do you want to set in the constructor. Something like this can be done.

```
class Gradebook
{
    public Gradebook(double testWeight, double quizWeight, double assignmentWeight, string[] studentNameArray)
    {
        this.TestWeight = testWeight;
        this.QuizWeight = quizWeight;
        this.AssingmentWeight = assignmentWeight;
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
        foreach(var name in studentNameArray)
            Students.Add(new Student(
                studentName: name, 
                age: 0,
                gradeBookTitle: ""
                )
            );
    }

    public double TestWeight { get; set; }

    public double QuizWeight { get; set; }

    public double AssingmentWeight { get; set; }

    public IList<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public Student(string studentName, int age, string gradeBookTitle)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a List of type Student in the constructor from the studentNameArray. However, the field age won't be set doing it this way. If you want to set the age too, you'll need to go back and modify the list or change the studentNameArray argument to an argument of type List.

```
private List<Student> _students;
private string _title;

public Gradebook(double testWeight, double quizWeight, 
          double assignmentWeight,  string[] studentNameArray)
{
    this._testWeight = testWeight;
    this._quizWeight = quizWeight;
    this._assignmentWeight = assignmentWeight;
    this._students = new List<Student>;

    foreach(var name in studentNameArray)
    {
        _students.Add(new Student(name, 0, this._title);
    }
}
```